# Paginate a table with jQuery from json object

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, pagination

I am able to create a table by reading my database into objects and then use the objects to populate the table. Is there a plugin that I can use to paginate my table every three objects.

I been trying several ones but haven't been able to get one that works. Any help will be greatly appreciated. If you need more code let me know and I'll post it.

Thanks

```
var columns = ["username", "user_id", "address", "state", "postal_code", "phone", "email"];

var level_classes = {
    "NEW": "new_client",
    "RENEWAL": "renewing_client",
    "CURRENT": "current_client"
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("obtainUsers.php", function(data) {
```

Comment: Why not paginate on the server? Otherwise the bandwidth benefits of pagination are pointless.

Comment: Are there plugins that could do that? I am very unfamiliar with pagination client or server side.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not always a bandwidth issue, can have all data available and have rendering or organizational issues also

Comment: There are lots of table plugins that will do all of this for you